# Presentability of natural numbers (number theory)

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, natural-numbers

Let $a,b,c,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $ab = c^n$.
**Task:** Show that there exist $d,e \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $a = d^n$ and $b = e^n$.

My thoughts about that are, that because of $gcd(a,b) = 1$ the following equality holds: $$ax + by = 1 \text{ with some } x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now I tried different approaches, e.g. writing $a = \frac{c^n}{b}$ and substituting this in the equality above. This lead to $$\frac{c^n}{b}x + by = 1 \iff b^2y - b + c^nx = 0$$
But putting this into the p-q-formula, I can't show the b is of the desired form and in analog way, that a if of the desired form.

I also tried multiplying the whole equality with b and got
$$abx + b^2y = b,$$ this lead me to $c^nx + b^2y = b$ and so to the same equality like above.

What could be a constructive approach to get this task solved?

Comment: Frequently, $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ is applied with expressing $a$ and $b$ by their prime factorizations, since the gcd tells you no prime appears (with positive power) in both factorizations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=(a,c)$. In particular $d|a$, and so $(d,b)=1$. We also have $d^n|c^n=ab$, and since $d^n$ is coprime to $b$ it follows that $d^n|a$.

Now, we clearly have $(\frac{a}{d}, \frac{c}{d})=1$. Hence also $((\frac{a}{d})^n, (\frac{c}{d})^n)=(\frac{a^n}{d^n}, \frac{c^n}{d^n})=1$. But note that both $\frac{a^n}{d^n}$ and $\frac{c^n}{d^n}$ are divisible by $\frac{a}{d^n}$. Thus $\frac{a}{d^n}=1$, and so $a=d^n$. And then:

$b=\frac{c^n}{a}=(\frac{c}{d})^n$

Comment: I've got two questions:
1st) Can we say that $(d,b) = 1$ because if $(d,b) > 1$, then we would have a common divisior $g > 1$ that divides $d$ (and so $a$ because of $d|a$) and that divides b because of $d|b$, and this would be a contradiction to $(a,b) = 1$? ㅤㅤㅤㅤ  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

2nd) Why do we have $d^n \mid c^n = ab$?

Comment: @X3nius If $g$ is a common divisor of $d$ and $b$ then since $d|a$ it is also a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. So we must have $g=1$, since $(a,b)=1$. As for the second question: since $d|c$ we can write $dm=c$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $d^nm^n=c^n$, and so $d^n|c^n$.